# What's the best way to implement different hotkeys across Linux, macOS, and Windows platforms, using react-hotkeys-hook useHotkeys?

Tags: reactjs, hotkeys

I've built an app and have created several hotkeys, using `react-hotkeys-hook`.

These were initially written on a Mac, and now I'm looking to implement them for Linux and Windows, after which I'll think about different browsers.  Right now, just focusing on Chrome.

Generally speaking, Mac apps tend to make use of the command key, whereas Linux and Windows tend to use the control key.  For example `meta+f` and `ctrl+f` are both `find` in Chrome.

I'd like to, if possible, use different hotkeys for different operating systems, rather than use the same mapping across all platforms.

I am already using `react-device-detect` in my app for other reasons, but something like this won't work, because `useHotkeys` is a hook.

```
if (isWindows) {
    useHotkeys(
        "ctrl+shift+1",
        () => {
            // do something
        },
        { enableOnFormTags: true, preventDefault: true }
    );
} else if (isMacOs) {
    useHotkeys(
        "meta+alt+1",
        () => {
            // do something
        },
        { enableOnFormTags: true, preventDefault: true }
    );
}
```

Any helpful advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to avoid conditional hook calls, but in your case the simplest and cleanest approach is to make the hook call only once and to put conditional logic inside the call.

For example:

```js
import { useHotkeys } from 'react-hotkeys-hook';

const Component = () => {
  const keystroke =
    isWindows
      ? "ctrl+shift+1"
      : isMacOs
        ? "meta+alt+1"
        : "meta+1";

  useHotkeys(
    keystroke,
    () => console.log(keystroke, 'pressed'),
    {
      enableOnFormTags: true,
      preventDefault: true
    }
  );

  return <div>Hello</div>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The second (much less readable) approach is to create different components for different operating systems, make them call the hook with the OS specific keystrokes, make them each return `null`, and render them conditionally in some other component body:

```js
import { useHotkeys } from 'react-hotkeys-hook';

const WinComponent = () => {
  useHotkeys(
    "ctrl+shift+1",
    () => console.log("ctrl+shift+1 pressed"),
    {
      enableOnFormTags: true,
      preventDefault: true
    }
  );

  return null
}

const MacComponent = () => {
  useHotkeys(
    "meta+alt+1",
    () => console.log("meta+alt+1 pressed"),
    {
      enableOnFormTags: true,
      preventDefault: true
    }
  );

  return null
}

const LinuxComponent = () => {
  useHotkeys(
    "meta+1",
    () => console.log("meta+1 pressed"),
    {
      enableOnFormTags: true,
      preventDefault: true
    }
  );

  return null
}

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {isWindows
        ? <WinComponent />
        : isMacOs
          ? <MacComponent />
          : <LinuxComponent />
      }

      <div>
        Hello
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```